# PhpStorm+Xdebug hits a breakpoint only when using external IP address

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Using MacOS Sierra, PhpStorm and Xdebug, web application configured on port 80 (not running from PhpStorm).

When browsing to `localhost:80/index.php`, PhpStorm won't stop on breakpoint, when accessing the external IP `192.168.1.2/index.php`, PhpStorm hits the breakpoint.

I would like to use `localhost` for debugging instead of the external IP.

Is there a way to make PhpStorm to work with `localhost`?

**P.S.** Visual Studio Code works in both scenarios (therefore I believe Xdebug and PhpStorm are working good).

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.29_5/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey=vagrant
xdebug.remote_host=0.0.0.0
```

Tried to set *xdebug.remote_host* to *127.0.0.1* and *localhost*, same behavior.

When debugging localhost:80, xdebug log show:

```
Log opened at 2017-01-03 14:06:36
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to ::1:9000.
W: Creating socket for '::1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (19).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-01-03 14:06:36
```

When using VS Code, there is no error and xdebug shows instead `I: Connected to client. :-)`

Comment: Please share your PhpStorm settings. Right now it could be that you created "debug server" entry in PhpStorm for IP address only -- check it at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`. if it's all good there -- collect xdebug related logs (from both IDE and xdebug sides).

Comment: *(for reference purposes)* The same on PhpStorm forums -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000010444-PHPStorm-Xdebug-hits-a-breakpoint-only-when-using-external-IP-address

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, I did tried to change Server settings, although they are created automatically when PHPStorm detects a connection (when connecting through external IP).

Comment: so .. what xdebug log has to say about such unsuccessful debug session?

Comment: Updated the question, @LazyOne, following the xdeubg logs, I can see changing 'xdebug.remote_connect_back' to 0 does make PHPStorm and xdebug to work together with localhost

Comment: From what I see -- PhpStorm does not listen on TCPv6 addresses -- only TCPv4 -- `::1` is IPv6 .. hence it will only work for IPv4 communications. By making `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` you told xdebug to use IP from `xdebug.remote_host` instead of auto-detection .. which (depending on your OS network settings) may put IPv6 in front of IPv4 interface.

Comment: Since it works now -- post your solution with explanation as an answer -- will be useful for other users in similar situation (answered posts will be easier to find .. plus it's an indication that post contain useful info)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting `xdebug.remote_connect_back` to 0 (the default value) solved the issue.

[Xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings):

> If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting is ignored and Xdebug will
>   try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request. It checks the
>   $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variables
>   to find out which IP address to use.

When Xdebug tried to connect to localhost, it used TCPv6, which PhpStorm doesn't support.
Changing `remote_connect_back`to 0 caused Xdebug to use the `remote_host` value, using TCPv4, which PhpStorm supports.